# Windows cmd .bat - Start a child process that runs simultaneously to parent and closes when parent does

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, child-process

So this may be impossible but I'll ask anyway

I have a log .bat script that is intended to collect info and usage time for a application. So what I want is a batch file that asks the user for some basic info, starts a child process or .bat file that allows the user to input more info, while the parent process starts and waits for a windows application (for example notepad.exe). I then want the parent and child process to exit once notepad.exe is closed by the user.

Generally this is what I have thus far ;

```
@echo off

set someinfo=
set /p someinfo="Enter Some Info Please: "
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%b/%%a/%%c)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set mytime=%%a:%%b)

:: Starting time and info
echo %someinfo%,%mytime%,%mydate% >> C:\Temp\MSuser.log 

:: This would be the child process for additional input 
start "Additional info" addinfo.bat 

::This is the software I want to start
start /Wait "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\notepad.exe"


:: Once user exits software write log string and exit .bat file
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%b/%%a/%%c)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set mytime=%%a:%%b) 

:: Ending time and info
echo %someinfo%,%mytime%,%mydate% >> C:\Temp\MSuser.log
```

The problem is when child process starts "addinfo.bat", the parent process waits for the child process complete before continuing to the next line of code (start /Wait "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\notepad.exe")

Is it possible to run the child process and continue parent process simultaneously? In addition is there a way to force the child process closed before exiting the parent process, maybe something like 'killpid' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will get the `PID` from your child process and kill it when the parent process finish:

```
@echo off

set someinfo=
set /p someinfo="Enter Some Info Please: "
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%b/%%a/%%c)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set mytime=%%a:%%b)

:: Starting time and info
echo %someinfo%,%mytime%,%mydate% >> C:\Temp\MSuser.log 

:: This would be the child process for additional input 
start "Additional info" adinfo.bat

::This is the software I want to start
start /Wait "" "notepad.exe"

:: Once user exits software write log string and exit .bat file
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%b/%%a/%%c)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set mytime=%%a:%%b) 

:: Ending time and info
echo %someinfo%,%mytime%,%mydate% >> C:\Temp\MSuser.log

for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('tasklist /v /fo csv ^| findstr /i "Additional info"') do set "$PID=%%a"
taskkill /PID %$PID%
```